# Merge dictionaries into dictionary of lists

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, merge

I have three dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
dict3 = {'c': 4, 'd': 4}
```

I want to 'merge' them into a dictionary of lists

```
merged_dict = {'a':[1, np.nan, np.nan],
               'b':[2, 3, np.nan],
               'c':[3, 4, 4],
               'd':[np.nan, np.nan, 4]}
```

There are keys that are in some dictionaries and not others which makes it kind of a pain to loop though.  Wondering what the cleanest way to do this is.

Comment: Why does the 4 in the d key come after the other elements in the list?

Comment: because it doesn't exist in the first two dictionaries

Comment: I think you just have bite the bullet and iterate over dictionaries and keys. You may have iterate once just to collect all keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to iterate over all the dictionaries first to collect all the keys, otherwise there's no way of knowing what keys are missing from each individual dict. Then you can build `merged_dict` with a dict comprehension.

```
import numpy as np

dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
dict3 = {'c': 4, 'd': 4}

all_dicts = (dict1, dict2, dict3)

keys = {k for d in all_dicts for k in d}
merged_dict = {k: [d.get(k, np.nan) for d in all_dicts] for k in keys} 
print(merged_dict)
```

**output**

```
{'a': [1, nan, nan], 'b': [2, 3, nan], 'c': [3, 4, 4], 'd': [nan, nan, 4]}
```

You *could* put the set comprehension inside the dict comprehension, but I think that makes the code harder to read.

```
merged_dict = {k: [d.get(k, np.nan) for d in all_dicts] 
    for k in {k for d in all_dicts for k in d}}
```

---

Actually, that double `for` loop in the set comp isn't so efficient. It probably doesn't matter much for small dicts, but if the dicts are large it'd be more efficient to do one of those loops at C speed using the `set.update` method:

```
keys = set()
for d in all_dicts:
    keys.update(d.keys())
```

This is probably even better:

```
keys = set().union(*all_dicts)
```

Thanks, Dan. D for that suggestion!

Here's yet another way, using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain
keys = set(chain.from_iterable(dicts))
```

Comment: @DanD. Good point! I'm surprised I didn't think of that way myself. :) Now I'm feeling tempted to write a `timeit` test to compare all these variations, including Brendan's...

Answer (score 4):

`pandas` does a good job at parsing dictionaries and merging them.  You can do something like this.

***setup***

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
dict3 = {'c': 4, 'd': 4}
```

***solution***

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(d) for d in [dict1, dict2, dict3]], axis=1)
df
```

[image]

To get the dictionary you are looking for.

```
df.T.to_dict('list')

{'a': [1.0, nan, nan],
 'b': [2.0, 3.0, nan],
 'c': [3.0, 4.0, 4.0],
 'd': [nan, nan, 4.0]}
```

Comment: I actually ended up picking up on this and went with this route because I was converting to a Pandas DataFrame anyway in the end and this was easier to read for me.  I would bet the other answer is faster so I will leave that as the selected answer unless this ends up being quicker but this code was an easier read for me.

Comment: @Chris The other answer is faster.  But I agree, this is more intuitive.

Comment: I'm conflicted as to which one to choose.  If this one ends up with more votes in the end I'll change my selection.

Comment: Don't be conflicted.  In fact, I'd choose the other answer because it answers your question more directly.  Either way it doesn't matter to me.  As far as points are concerned, I'll get plenty from answering lots of questions.  I'm happy to see you actively selecting an answer at all.  I find that far more important.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
from itertools import chain

dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
keys = set(chain(*[d.keys() for d in dicts]))
merged_dict = {k: [d.get(k, np.nan) for d in dicts] for k in keys}
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the answer above and 100% correct but a little less explanation so I am going with that one but I up-voted this one since it's correct as well.